# pythonic way to do checks before imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to develop python code for an inhouse framework which can either run in the system's standard python environment or sometimes requires a custom environment to be active. For example, to be able to load certain modules.
Because an `ImportError` might not be too obvious for any user, I would like to give the user a proper error message, explaining the issue.

Some sample code might look like this:

```
# standard imports...
import sys

import numpy as np

# import which requires special environment
import myspecialmodule

# [...]
```

One method would be to check for `ImportError`s like this:

```
# standard imports...
import sys

import numpy as np

# import which requires special environment
try:
    import myspecialmodule
except ImportError:
    print('not in the env', file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

# [...]
```

However, that is quite tedious to do, especially if there are many such scripts or if there are many imports. The question is then, which import has failed, if you do not want to repeat the `try`/`except` several times.

Now, I wrote a function `guard()` which checks for the existence of the environment in another way:

```
import sys
import os


def guard():
    # assume the environment sets this special variable
    if 'MYSPECIALENV' in os.environ:
        # do more checks if the environment is correctly loaded
        # if it is, simply:
        return

    print("The environment is not loaded correctly. "
          "Run this script only in the special environment", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

I altered the imports on the script:

```
# standard imports...
import sys

import numpy as np

# import which requires special environment
guard()
import myspecialmodule

# [...]
```

The advantage over the `try`/`except` method is, that an `ImportError` is still raised even if the environment is loaded.

But the issue is, that code linters like [isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort/) do not like function calls before imports.
Now, one could add configuration to isort to skip this section...

Furthermore, for a reader of the code, it might not be too obvious what is going on.
Of course, I could add some comments explaining it...

Another method I thought of is to write a module which does the job of guard, i.e.:

```
# file: guard/__init__.py
import sys
import os

if 'MYSPECIALENV' not in os.environ:
    print("The environment is not loaded correctly. "
          "Run this script only in the special environment", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

```
# standard imports...
import sys

import numpy as np

# import which requires special environment
import guard
import myspecialmodule

# [...]
```

but this might be even less obvious, especially as imports might be sorted in a different way (again thinking about isort).

Is there a better, more pythonic way to do such things before importing a module? Especially one that is obvious for a future developer as well.

Comment: So in small words, you want to check if a package exist in a virtual environment or not?

Comment: *"code linters […]do not like function calls before imports"* The linter is **your** servant, not the other way around.

Comment: If  you're exiting anyway when the module isn't found, why not simply let the ImportError bubble up? A developer should be able to understand that easily.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav yes. But the check might be extended, like in the guard function.

Comment: @KlausD. thats true. However, in this situation, adding a lot of comments for the linter might also make things worse and unreadable in the end... but yes, in this situation it might be a good idea to instruct the linter to allow this exceptional function-before-import.

Comment: @JanWilamowski the intention is to make this script work for a user who does not even know what an import is. Of course, a developer who has knowledge of the system can easily figure out what happened.

Comment: @reox You can use `try`, `except`  and `finally` maybe.

Comment: You could add a custom [meta path finder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path) but you'd still have to register it. For that, you would probably need access to the users' environment variables or Python installation.